# File content is missing after downloading the file manually from azure blob storage explorer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I've created word document with "Test Document" content and saved as pdf. And I changed the file name with a valid GUID and extension to '.enc' and I uploaded the file to azure blob storage from C# using the following methods: "UploadFromStream" and "UploadFromByteArrayAsync".  Just FYI, those 2 methods are from "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob" namespace.  The file has been uploaded successfully with those 2 methods.

I opened azure storage explorer manually and downloaded the file from it and changed the file extension to ".pdf" from ".enc".  I opened the pdf file and I noticed that content "Test Document" is missed.

What could be the reason and what's the best method to upload the file to azure blob storage without losing the contents?

the following is the actual code that I'm using:

```
 public bool UploadToBlob(byte[] content, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(content))
            {
                var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_configuration["containerName"]);
                var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                blockBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = 256 * 1024;
                //blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw ex;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

"

Comment: Please edit your question to show actual code, along with any other details. You gave some general hints about your code, but it's difficult to know what was actually done.

Comment: @DavidMakogon  Just updated the question with the actual code.  Please have a look at them and correct me where I'm wrong plz.